# It is able to be possible/ She is able to have drunk

Tags: modal-verbs, present-perfect

If **"can"** and **"be able to"** are interchangable sometimes, for example:

*She **can** speak Latin = She **is able to** speak Latin*

Can **"be able to"** be used instead of **"can"** in:

*She **can't have drunk** that much coffee = She **isn't able to have drunk** that much coffee*

*It **can be possible** that he has forgotten about us = It **is able to be possible** that he has forgotten about* *us* ?

Comment: Both starting examples use *can* in a wooly way. Then converting to *be able to* makes them worser, no, worsted.

Comment: It's some "wool" humor or what? I don't understand

Comment: *If "can" and "be able to" are interchangable sometimes,* This is your problem. You have chosen times when they are not interchangeable. *She can't have drunk...* - this uses "can" to express an probability/possibility. The second one does too but it is not really idiomatic. We would say "It **could** be possible..." When *can* is used to express a possibility or request permission, its meaning is not "to be able to".

Comment: I was told "It can be possible" was not a good sentence. Using "could" - "Could it be possible" makes everything fine?

Comment: All of those constructions are syntactically sound. The first example is fine, but the second is unidiomatic and awkward.

Comment: "Can be possible" - fine, "could be posible" - awkward?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko I don't see much difference between *can be possible* and *could be possible.* There's nothing wrong with having one possibility modify another one. *It's possible we will be offered the chance to work from home permanently.* But most of the time it's somewhat redundant and could be made stylistically simpler.

Comment: It is possible to say almost anything. Whether or not it is English is another matter, but if you do not know I suspect you should be posting on English Language Learners, rather than here.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is "no."

In your first example, the infinitive "to speak" is used following the verb phrase "is able." This principle doesn't work with the next example because "to have drunk" is not the infinitive form of "to drink." If you want to use the infinitive form, you would have:

> She isn't able to drink that much coffee.

...which is a perfectly fine sentence that would be equivalent to "She can't drink that much coffee." This, of course, is not the same as your original "She can't have drunk that much coffee."

As for your next sentence, "It can be possible that he has forgotten about us," I find that construction awkward and undesirable, but close to the perfectly acceptable question "Can it be possible that he has forgotten about us?"

I can't think of how to make that work with "is able," neither am I able to think of how to make that work with "is able."