# Can't have drunk VS Isn't able to have drunk VS Wasn't able to have drunk

Tags: negation, modal-verbs, present-perfect

I found a good sentence:

***She can't have drunk that much coffee***

It seems to be correct. Why isn't the next thing correct then if **"can"** and **"be able"** can mean the same thing?

***She isn't able to have drunk that much coffee***

I was told that it would be correct if we wrote the sentence with **"wasn't"**:

***She wasn't able to have drunk that much coffee***

Why so?

***Can't have*** drunk - correct

***Wasn't able to have*** drunk - correct

***Isn't able to have*** drunk - bad

Comment: Could you please give the context in which you think **She isn't able to have drunk that much coffee** might be a valid sentence. :)

Comment: Should there be some context to define whether it's correct? Can't I simply equal it to "She can't have drunk that much coffee"? Aren't these sentences both correct and don't they mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes, there should be context. Honestly, it is impossible to overestimate how important context is in English. Context really does make a difference.

Comment: Okay, let's have context. I come back home. I have a sister and a brother. We all like coffee. Unfortunatelly, I can't find anything though we've bought 5kg coffee recently. I ask if my brother knows something. He says that our siter has drunk everything. I say "She can't have drunk that much coffee" and my brother says "Yeah, she is not able to have drunk that much coffee but it's true!".

Comment: Thanks, but your brother's comment makes no sense - if she is not able to do that, then it cannot be true. Your brother should reply: "Yeah, I did not believe that she **was** able to have drunk that much coffee but it's true!"

Comment: 1) "If she is not able to HAVE DONE" but not "if he is not able to DO". 2) If he replies "I didn't believe that she was able to have..." then I should have replied "She couldn't have..." instead of "She can't have..."

Answer (score 1):

I replied in a comment to your question in this post. [It is able to be possible/ She is able to have drunk](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536676/it-is-able-to-be-possible-she-is-able-to-have-drunk). To expand upon this:

**She isn't able** describes her current [in]ability.

**to have drunk that much coffee** describes a past action.

In this context, a current ability cannot describe a past action.

Your choices are

1. Expressing a fact/belief/opinion

A: “Look! Twenty empty coffee cups! This is a mystery! *She **isn't** able to (can’t) **drink** [i.e. currently] that much coffee.”* Or

A: “The coffee machine is empty and Maria has disappeared. *She **wasn't** able to (couldn’t) **have drunk** that much coffee,* [i.e. at some time in the past] therefore some other people must have been here.” Or

2. Expressing a probability/possibility

A: “That litre carafe of coffee is empty! I know that the cat likes coffee, and I left her alone for five minutes, but *she **wouldn't have been** able **to drink** (couldn't have drunk) that much coffee.*” [i.e. in the time allowed and because of its size] (The cat is assumed to be alive) Or

A: “I don’t think that it was coffee that killed her. Maria drank a lot of coffee every day but *she **wouldn't have been** able **to (couldn't) have drunk** that much coffee.*”

*(You have also introduced "if" clauses - these have their own guidance: you should research "if conditionals".)*

Comment: 1) I understand "She isn't able to (can’t) drink" and I understand "She wasn't able to drink" but I don't understand "She wasn't able to have drunk". As far as I can see "to have drunk" is past of "she wasn't". If current [in]ability in present can't be combined with "have done", how can [in]ability in past be combined with "have done" if "have done" is past of "wasn't able"? It's symmetrical.2) I understand "She wouldn't have been able to drink" but I don't clearly understand "She wouldn't have been able to have drunk". Can I equal it to "I wouldn't have believed she had drunk"?